# Using variables in SASS percentage function

Tags: css, sass

For some reason my SASS is not compiling when I do this:

Suppose this is my global variable:

```
$gridColumnCount: 12;

@function gridCalc($colNumber, $totalColumns) {
    @return percentage(($colNumber / $totalColumns));
}

@mixin columns($columnSpan: 1) {
    width: gridCalc($columnSpan, $gridColumnCount);
}
```

This error is returned & the `scss` file does not compile.

> Syntax error: "1/12" is not a unitless number for `percentage'

It seems to not be calculating the percentage but returning the arguments as a string.

If I change the mixin to use non-variable arguments, everything works perfectly... like this:

```
@mixin columns($columnSpan: 1) {
    width: gridCalc(4, 12);
}
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong.

FYI: **SASS version: 3.2.2**

Comment: Hmmm... works for me using the [online compiler](http://sass-lang.com/try.html). How are you actually using the mixin? Sounds like you're passing in a bad arugment.

Comment: Like this at the moment:

    `@for $i from 1 to $gridColumnCount {
        .span#{$i}, .mq-alpha-resize-to#{$i}  { @include columns(#{$i});  }
    }`

Comment: but using the online tester, I see that the `columns(#{$i});` should be like this instead `columns($i);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Wesley Murch I figured out what was wrong with my code. I should have called my mixin using this syntax:

```
@for $i from 1 to $gridColumnCount {
    .span#{$i}, .mq-alpha-resize-to#{$i}  { @include columns($i);  }
}
```

NOT this:

```
@for $i from 1 to $gridColumnCount {
    .span#{$i}, .mq-alpha-resize-to#{$i}  { @include columns(#{$i});  }
}
```

The reason was that SASS was [interpolating](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) the numbers.