# calc() not working properly in CSS3

Tags: css, calc

I'm trying to make one div with height 100% - 130px;

Code is:

```
height: calc(100% - 130px); // Here 80px of TOC-header and 50 of TOC-footer
height: -moz-calc(100% - 130px);
height: -webkit-calc(100% - 130px);
```

When I edit it with browser console(Inspect Element) it works well. But when I apply the same in code it shows calc(-30%); And due to that the contents get no visibility.

I've attached a screenshot below of firebug. Really confusing moment.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: A demo would be useful but it might be that the parent doesn't have a declared height.

Comment: Sorry for webkit. I've updated it. And adding demo soon.

Comment: The unprefixed property should come last: it's always the last one supported by a browser with the newest way of declaring it and prefixed versions can be seen as fallback (for example flexbox and gradients evolved twice so 3 versions at least, sigh)

Comment: Please check problem demo here. http://jsfiddle.net/enworl/bqgj0rsy/

Comment: Did you want something like http://jsfiddle.net/bqgj0rsy/2/ ?

Comment: Yep. It's working fine here in the fiddle. But the same code not working in my repo.

Answer (score 0):

Saying `height: 100%` refers to the same height of it's parents height.

**In [your case](http://jsfiddle.net/enworl/bqgj0rsy/)**, `.element1` has a `height` of `100%` which is not recognizable. Set a real height to this element and you will see the expected output.

**For example:**

```
.element1 {
    height :200px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/bqgj0rsy/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your item in another div, give it 100% height with a padding top or bottom of 130px or padding bottom and top of 65px. This way you can even position your element vertically.

Comment: You are right, my bad. I had this [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274599/sass-calculate-percent-minus-px) the other time and somehow I remembered that this was the problem. I still believe it is best to wrap the element for better control and older browsers.