# Can Sass perform mixed arithmetics?

Tags: css, sass, expression

I am in a bit of a dilemma here...
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274599/sass-calculate-percent-minus-px) stack overflow question's accepted answer, Sass cannot process expressions involving px and % together. However, if I go to the [Sass Guide](http://sass-lang.com/guide) and scroll down to the **Operators** section, there is a very clearly written expression involving px and % together. Is this a mistake in the Sass documentation, or does this expression really work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what it is you are trying to achieve it's hard to answer. The operators you are referring to are converting px to %...not adding incompatible value expressions.

And yes, the SASS guide is correct and it does work.

Input

```
div {
  width: 600px / 900px *  100%;
}
```

Output

```
div {
  width: 66.66666667%;
}
```

https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/7fde603028e0ab2f47609523b8ea7894

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. I am going to state what I gather from this. Please tell me if I am wrong - In their example writing those 'px's are redundant, i.e., 600/900 * 100% or 600em/900em * 100% would mean the same thing, right?